# What things should be kept in mind while assigning static IP addresses to Virtual Machines

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, gateway

I always face problems pinging the base machine whenever I assign statics IPs to VMs.
I also don't understand what gateway IP should I give,to connect to the internet or just to be able ping the Base machine.
Kindly keep the explanation as simple as possible.
I use oracle VM Virtual Box.
Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the gateway,Should I give the same gateway as my windows machine.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VM Virtual Box but basically you have to check which Virtual Network is defined in your virtualization software.  This is the network all your VMs use.  (There might be more than one Virtual Network set up, but let's keep things simple.)

The Virtual Network settings include the network range (e.g. 192.168.88.0/24) and gateway (e.g. 192.168.88.1).  Often there's also a range for DHCP addressing (e.g. 192.168.88.200-254).  Here, you can assign to your virtual machines any static IP from 192.168.88.2 to 192.168.88.199.

To answer the question in your comment: no, the gateway of your VM is not necessarily the same as your host machine; it must be set as specified above.